# Importance sampling for a parameterized family of distributions using a wide distribution from the same family

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, prior, importance-sampling

I'm motivated here by a problem for robust Bayesian analysis. Let $l(Y|X)$ be the likelihood and let $\{p_\xi(X)\}$ be a parameterized family of prior distributions where $\xi$ denotes the hyperparameters. For example, they could be Gaussian distributions where the hyperparameters are different choices for the mean and covariance.

For some choice of $\xi$ the unnormalized posterior is $q(X|Y) = l(Y|X)\cdot p_\xi(X)$. I want to see how the choice of $\xi$ affects the expectation $\mathbb{E}_q(f)$ for some function $f$. Now, suppose I am able to reasonably sample from each posterior with MCMC. But, I can't hope to do this for all the choices of $\xi$ that I'm interested in. So, instead I want to estimate the expectation using importance sampling for my range of targets. There are a lot of schemes for doing this. I am wondering if something basic could work, like running MCMC using a prior from the same family that is wide and covers all the other priors I am looking at.

Comment: The issue with picking one particular $\xi^0$ towards $p_{\xi^0}$ being the importance function is that this distribution must dominate or have fatter tails than all other $p_{\xi}$'s which is uncommon.

Comment: I see. So, for example, if I am considering a family of Gaussian distributions, it could be reasonable to use a single wide Gaussian distribution. But, if I am considering a family of gamma distributions, there isn't necessarily a single gamma distribution that that will dominate the others.